# Why do people say not to overwater basil, when it grows better in standing water?

Tags: watering, basil

I have a basil plant that is approximately doubling in size every day while in standing water, and was wondering why people say not to overwater basil?

Comment: Because growing something in just water is not the same thing as growing a plant in soaking wet soil, see here - its about rooting in water, but the information's the same http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/why-do-plants-root-when-placed-in-water-but-die-in-standing-water/5177#5177

Comment: @Bamboo no, it's really doing well in water, not just rooting in water.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but if you read the question and answer I've linked to, it saves me having to say it all over  again - the answer's exactly the same whether you're growing in water or rooting in water.

Comment: Please explain why their bad advice is better than what I've found works?

Comment: Whose bad advice? You asked why basil shouldn;t be overwatered growing in soil, when yours is growing just fine in plain water, did you not? Did you read the answer in the link?

Comment: for example: http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/basil/basil-watering-tips.htm

Comment: There is a full explanatory answer to your question in the link I provided - I do not need links to other perfectly good advice about growing basil in pots.  If you have read the answer I linked to, but are having trouble grasping it,  then fine, ask questions about that. If that's not the case, then there's no need for further discussion. If you don't like the answer I gave, then maybe someone else will supply another one you like better - or not.

Comment: Our basil is growing very well in standing water, but the experts say it should be well drained, why do they lie about what to do?

Comment: Because, as I've already said, growing in soil and growing in water are NOT the same thing. And they're not 'lying', they're spot on accurate. Read the answer I linked to, then you might get it.... If you want to argue further, move it to chat...

Comment: Black Thumb, I've never thought that anyone could have a black thumb but you are changing my opinion.  My goodness, you ask experts for advice and then you challenge THEM?  Growing plants is a huge cycle with lots of sciences you need to understand and how it all fits together.  No way can one isolate a little thing without acknowledging all the parts included.  That was pretty arrogant to go up against Bamboo, I kid you not.  Listen and learn or quit asking questions you THINK you already have an answer.  My goodness!

Comment: @stormy I guess this question needs to be asked by picture, not by text.

Comment: I believe you your basil is doing well.  Have you heard of aquaponics?  That is what you are doing.  Aquaponics done correctly is pretty cool but what a headache!  Being off on any math for fertilizer, other chemicals or even a disease will quickly effect everything.  Send a picture of your basil.  (Try Thai basil!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many plants grow fine in water. That's the basis for hydroponics. The main methods are deep water culture, flood and drain, and thin film. They all have in common moving water to ensure that the dissolved oxygen levels remain high enough so that the area around the roots doesn't become anoxic. If they do, the roots suffocate, die, and rot.

If your basil plant is doing well in muddy water, then you must have enough surface area to allow sufficient oxygenation for the plant to survive. Basil is commonly grown hydroponically so it's a good choice to try this out. But muddy water is not a sufficiently controlled environment for commercial growers. It may or may not have enough nutrients for the plant, and growers want to control all the variables to get the best growth.

Comment: Kratky system would beg to differ with that first paragraph.

Comment: But I didn't include Kratky method which I recall has an air gap under the plants to allow air roots to develop.

Answer (score 3):

Just found that there are no answers here so here goes.  Growing stuff in water is just fine, if there is enough light, ventilation and proper amounts of chemicals/fertilizers.  One basil plant no big deal.  But most gardeners like to use the NORMAL way to grow plants that are not water plants in soil that is available all around us.  When one over waters in SOIL, like Bamboo explained, you've got the perfect conditions for ROOT ROT (and other fungal, bacterial conditions).

[Oh look what I found!! Check this out!](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/if-its-possible-to-overwater-a-plant-then-how-do-plants-grow-hydroponically)

Comment: So I'm applying hydroponic theory with soil in the pot also.

Comment: No you are NOT.  arrrggghhh!  Water with known chemicals flowing to allow plenty of oxygen renovation does not happen in soil!!  Water plants have devised ways to use STAGNANT water/soil but most plants do not get enough oxygen in stagnant, soggy soil.  I would love to take a ruler and smack you upside the head, black thumb.  GO READ what Bamboo sent you.  Then I think we shall give you a pop quiz!

Comment: I just noticed today I have roots floating in the water, lol

Comment: To get more oxygen?

Comment: i dunno, maybe, or because it wants to pick up more from being on the surface of the water.

Comment: Pick up more O2?  Yeah, that is what I meant.  Are you doing hydroponic gardening?

Comment: No, I'm doing soil with water sitting on top.

Comment: Sigh, you are reinventing the wheel.  Knock yourself out.  You do not see plants they way you should be seeing, understanding botany sweetheart.  That is a fact.  Have you even looked up hydroponic gardening?  Do you know anything about soils?  Again, Master Gardener program would be perfect for you...within a few months you'll understand at least the basics.  And sorry, you won't be discovering BETTER ways to grow plants anytime soon.  Save yourself some energy and save some of the plants you will be using for experiments...Master Gardeners or go to University for Horticulture, Botany!!

Comment: When you take these classes it would behoove you to listen, take notes and only ask questions that are relevant for the class.  There is so much to learn and from your questions there is an awful lot of basics you have to learn.  In your defense you ARE a gardener, just need to get a good foundation under your butt!  Grins!

Answer (score 2):

*Growth better* maybe, but if you are not selling things per weight, possibly it is not the better solution

Many vegetables gives much more savour when there is some stress on plants.

When doing home gardening, one should not check about quantities: we will never compete with wholesale (with prices), but we can produce much more tasty vegetables (which wholesale cannot really do, if not much pricey).