# Can geranium (pelargonium hortorum) live in water?

Tags: plant-care

I am interested in growing some indoor plants in water only, with some added fertilizer.

I am wondering if geranium (pelargonium hortorum), like pothos can live in water.

A quick google search did not reveal much information about this and I was wondering if anyone has any experience on this subject.

Comment: Can you clarify please - geranium is a common name for Pelargonium, or the botanical name for (cranesbill) Geranium. Pothos (botanical name Epipremnum) is entirely unrelated to either of these plants - its not clear whether you're asking about geranium specifically and if you are,  which geranium you mean.

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks a lot for your clarification! I guess I meant pelargonium hortorum. Nevertheless, do you agree with the answer below? If that's true I guess I should reword/edit my question to any plant.

Comment: This answer is also interesting: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/5177/27691
(credits to @Bamboo)

Comment: I'm surprised no one else has mentioned this but geranium easily get root rot when they sit in wet soil. I've killed a few outdoor geranium by watering them too frequently. This doesn't mean you can't grow them indoors in a cup of water, but they're definitely not the first plant I would choose for that. Even when I propogate geranium I do so by putting them in soil and not water to avoid rot. If you're looking for other plants to grow indoors in water I would try coleus and sweet potatoes instead.

Comment: Not entirely - see my answer below

Comment: @NatanYellin - it wasn't mentioned because it was  not clear whether the asker meant Pelargonium or actual Geranium...

Comment: I added an additional link that is very excellent/educational in teaching how to set-up a simple semi-hydroponics system that will work for all plants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grow any plant in hydroponically, even succulents, as long as you are providing them with the right nutrients and the correct watering system.  If you just want to put it in a container of water it will grow, if you maintain the right amount of oxygen and nutrients.

Oxygen by changing the water often.  Weekly at minimum.  Or you can provide an oxygenator/bubbler, then you do not need change the water as often.

The container should not be see through, otherwise you will always be cleaning algae off the inside of the container.  If you start to get algae growth your water is getting too much light.  Figure out a way to block the light.

It is very important to make sure you keep the leaves and stem dry.   Putting a layer of stone between the water and the foliage will help.

Also, think about heat.  Plants that grow in warm conditions, do not like cold water.  Even room temperature water maybe too cold.  I keep all my semi-hydroponic plants, which includes many succulent at 25c (78f). This is a good growing temperature.  Any warmer and the water can not hold enough oxygen.

[Semi-hydroponics System useful for all Plants](https://firstrays.com/free-information/basic-orchid-culture/semi-hydroponics/)

[Gardening Know How - Water gardening](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/projects/growing-houseplants-in-water.htm)

Answer (score 2):

There are some plants which can continue to grow in water relatively long term, but by no means all,especially if you are not using a full hydroponic system. Pelargonium in particular are not well suited to being left sitting in water long term, they are likely to rot even in the short term. This link might be helpful https://thepracticalplanter.com/plants-that-grow-in-water/ but note that some of the plants mentioned are intended only to be rooted in water, not necessarily left in it to grow on permanently - those that can are mentioned nearer the end of the link.